# Why isn't 笑う usually used with に particle?

Tags: grammar, nuances, particles, particle-に

From what I understand, there are two types of intransitive verbs (might be wrong)

1. The intransitive verb can act with a direct object or direction with the particle に

> 私は学校**に**行きます。
>
> 私は友達**に**会います。
>
> 私は道**に**迷います。

2. The intransitive verb is by itself, and can't be used with the に particle.

> 私は朝早く起きます。
>
> 私は玩具で遊びます。

---

But I was told that 笑う fits under 2. and is not normally used with the に particle.

For example, if I want to say "I laughed at the cat", why can't I say 私は猫に笑いました?

But why is is okay in this sentence?

> 彼らは皆彼の冗談**に**笑いました。
>
> They all laughed at his joke.

If I want to say "laughed at (noun)" why can't I use the に particle in certain cases?

And since 笑う can also be a transitive verb, why isn't を used in the sentence above?

Can someone please explain the grammar behind this?

Comment: Where does your premise of 笑う being only an intransitive verb come from?

Comment: @l'électeur I realized that 笑う can also be transitive. Various dictionaries online listed 笑う as intransitive, and omitted the transitive definition...

Comment: As a caution, don't look at English 'laugh at' and assume that Japanese has to have something equivalent to 'at'. Xを笑う is largely equivalent to English 'laugh at X'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

笑う has several meanings (laugh, smile, grin, chuckle...) and is an intransitive verb:

> 声を出して笑う laugh out loud
>   冗談を聞いて笑う hear a joke and laugh
>   笑って挨拶する greet with a smile

When used with the indirect object particle に:

> 冗談に笑う laugh at a joke (in the sense "hear a joke and laugh" "a joke causes you to laugh")
>   <sub>(I think ～を聞いて笑う would be more common/natural than ～に笑う)</sub>

---

笑う can also be a transitive verb, and can be used with the direct object particle を. According to 明鏡国語辞典:

> わらう【笑う】
>   〘**他**五〙ばかにする。嘲笑{ちょうしょう}する。あざわらう。「一円**を笑う**者は一円に泣く」

When used as a transitive verb, 笑う means "laugh at~~" in the sense of "ridicule" "deride" "sneer at~~" "make fun of~~".

> 人の失敗を笑う laugh at another's failure (in the sense of "ridicule / make fun of~~")
>   人(のこと)を笑う laugh at others (in the sense of "ridicule / make fun of~~")

---

Now back to your examples...

> 彼らは皆彼の冗談に笑いました。

It'd be understood as "They all laughed at his joke" in the sense of "They heard his joke and laughed" "His joke made them laugh".

> 私は猫に笑いました。

It'd probably be understood as "I laughed at a cat" in the sense of "I saw a (funny) cat and laughed/smiled" (≂「私は猫を見て笑いました。」)
To say "I laughed at a cat" in the sense of "ridiculed / made fun of a cat", you'd say 私は猫を笑いました.

Comment: Is it more common to use 笑う with another verb such as [Noun]を見て笑う or を聞いて笑う than to say [Noun]に/を笑う? If I said 猫に笑いました it adds the nuance that I "saw" the cat and laughed? Vs. 猫を笑いました which means I laughed directly at the cat? So に is actually を見て?

Comment: @shade I don't think [Noun] **に**笑う is so common. I don't think **を**笑う is uncommon. You'd say 猫に笑いました when seeing a cat made you / caused you to laugh. 猫を笑いました means a different thing, and has a negative nuance, "ridiculed, provoked, made a fool of a cat". The に in [Noun]に笑った would be rephrased as [Noun]を見て笑った or [Noun]を聞いて笑った, depending on what caused you to laugh.

Comment: @Chocolate Great answer. I'm not sure if you fully understand the phrase 'make a fool of' though. "make a fool of another's failure" doesn't really make sense. You can only make a fool of a person, not of their actions, e.g. "He made a fool out of me when he asked me that trick question". This seems to be a good definition "trick or deceive (someone) so that they look foolish.". So can 笑う be used with this definition i.e. can the object of  笑う be a person.

Comment: @user3856370 Ohh..  I think "Trick or deceive (someone) so that they look foolish" would be closer to かつぐ or 笑い者にする. The object of ～を笑う can be either a person or a thing/action. Does "ridicule + someone's action" sound strange, too? and what about "make fun of someone's failure"?

Comment: @Chocolate I think both of those phrases would sound slightly better with a person as the object, but they both sound fine with an action as the object too. You could say , for example, 'He made fun of the fact that I couldn't whistle', or 'he made fun of me for not being able to whistle.', but you would never say 'he made a fool out of my inability to whistle'. You could say something like 'He made a fool out of me by trying to get me to whistle when he knew I couldn't'

Comment: @user3856370 おお、なるほろ・・・  ありがとうございます！ （＾＾）