# Why is に used in that sentence?

Tags: particle-に, particle-で, に-and-で

> でもほんとに、エピソード21**に**は涙が出るほど笑ったよ。

For some reason I feel like it would be better without the に (in bold) but I can't explain why.

Another person said that で would be better but I think that it changes the meaning completely. I mean that （登場人物の）Aさんは エピソード21では涙が出るほど笑ったよ would be okay but if the subject is not a character of the episode で is not appropriate.

Could you explain the reason behind using に here?

Comment: Related, maybe?　https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/59047/9831

Comment: That looks like it! According to the answer there the に can't really be omitted if I understood correctly.